# Can I change glui panel background colour?

Tags: c++, opengl, pyqt

I am using glui to add a control panel to my OpenGl code. This is a visualisation interface for a large scale simulation platform written in C++.

I was wondering if it is possible to make changes to the background colours of the panels?

If this is not possible, can anyone comment on how slower my display will become if I switch to using pyQt with OpenGL? And would it be possible to access information on my C++ classes and display them with a pyQt approach? (I am happy to make this a second thread if you think it is better that way.)

Answer (score 1):

For background color change of glui-based panel, its not clear what you are asking but I don't see why it would not support such a basic op. Update: I would try using `glClearColor` like on [that link](http://eecs.oregonstate.edu/capstone/opengl/sample.cpp).

For speed it really depends on what and how you're going to use opengl: see [pyopengl: Could it replace c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2488730/pyopengl-could-it-replace-c) for a good discussion.

For using your c++ from python this is usually relatively easy by using SWIG (swig.org). You tell SWIG what parts of your c++ api you want to access from python and SWIG generates the code to make your c++ available as a python module.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the thread does help. For the background colours, I am literally asking for a colour change, my purpose is purely to make panels look "prettier" than a series of grey panels, for the collaborators and students I will be showing the simulation results. I know it is very simple, I failed to find how to do it, or if it is possible at all, without going into the main source code. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the update, I can use the clear colour setting to manage the background of the main drawing window, there are no problems there. The problem is, I am trying to find a way to apply this to the control panels (added with GLUI_Master.create_glui_subwindow(...) etc). None of the documentation has any image with the control panel display colours altered, so I am starting to think this may not be possible at all, without changing the source.

Comment: Gosh, so close, frustrating isn't it... If you do determine it can't be done, may be good to put a comment and close this.